# Align ImageView to end to text in textView

Tags: android, textview, imageview, android-constraintlayout

I need to align an imageView to end of textView, both are constraint on end to a checkbox.
The problem with my code is imageView always appears on the start of Checkbox and not where text in textView ends. Can anyone help

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMerchantTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin4"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin8"
        android:layout_marginStart="@dimen/margin16"
        android:drawablePadding="@dimen/padding4"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:maxWidth="@dimen/width200"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="@dimen/textSize12"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@id/tvMerchantSubtitle"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/cbMerchantSelect"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/ivMerchantLogo"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivMerchantLogo" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbMerchantSelect"
        android:layout_width="@dimen/width16"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/height16"
        android:layout_marginEnd="@dimen/margin16"
        android:button="@drawable/ic_round_checkbox"
        android:clickable="false"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

I am using glide to set image to textView end drawable -

```
Glide.with(this)
                .load(url)
                .into(object : CustomTarget<Drawable?>(
                    DisplayUtils.dpToPx(this.context, R.dimen.width30),
                    DisplayUtils.dpToPx(this.context, R.dimen.height20)
                ) {

                    override fun onLoadCleared(@Nullable placeholder: Drawable?) {}

                    override fun onResourceReady(
                        resource: Drawable,
                        transition: com.bumptech.glide.request.transition.Transition<in Drawable?>?
                    ) {
                        mBinding.inPaymentMethod.tvMerchantTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                            null,
                            null,
                            resource,
                            null
                        )
                    }
                })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvMerchantTitle"` to your ImageView

Example Code:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/white">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvMerchantTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="4dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:drawablePadding="4dp"
        android:ellipsize="middle"
        android:maxWidth="200dp"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:textSize="12sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivMerchantLogo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivMerchantLogo"
        android:text="@string/app_name"/>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivMerchantLogo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@+id/tvMerchantTitle"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"/>
    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatCheckBox
        android:id="@+id/cbMerchantSelect"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
        android:clickable="false"
        android:gravity="end"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@id/ivMerchantLogo"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/ivMerchantLogo" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Output for above code is like:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Textview's text is too long,
Textview and ImageView will be over Checkbox's left
How could make <ImageView's right> is not over <Checkbox's left>
do not use textview drawableright
like below

[image: 1]